# CakePHP 3.2 application extremely slow

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My application is running extremely slow and I cant figure out whats causing it. Database is running on SQL Server, don't know if that could be the problem. For example, I'm using jQuery UI autocomplete widget, and after typing text in the textbox it takes about 8 seconds to load autocomplete suggestions(which is obviously too long for this kind of widget). This is query that I use in the ajax method for autocomplete:

```
  $content = TableRegistry::get('Content');
  $data = $content->find('all', ['limit' => 5,  'conditions' => [
                        'OR' => [
                            'Content.slug LIKE ' => "%" . $term . "%",
                            'Content.title LIKE ' => "%" . $term . "%",
                        ]
                ]])->contain(['ContentTypes']);
```

Also, according to debug kit, it takes about 24 seconds for the front page to load, Sql Log is showing total time of 2502 ms and 39 queries. Timer panel is showing that *Controller.startup* is having 20,156.21 ms request time. All of this applies when I run the application on the local machine, when I run it in the cloud, time is twice as high.

Comment: Where you run your application i.e. in server or local?

Comment: Does Your DB schema uses indexes?

Comment: @Bogdan: no, it does not use indexes

Comment: `Sql Log is showing total time of 2502 ms` That's huge. The problem you have is likely not the your app is slow, it's that you're issuing sql queries that are inefficient/slow/inappropriate. `no, it does not use indexes` - well, there's your problem! (or one of your problems). First identify a _specific cause_ for slowness, and then investigate why that's happening. e.g. how long does it take to issue the same query on the db directly? If it's not much quicker the problem is the query, not the code running it. "My app is too slow" is not itself an answerable question.

Comment: @AD7six: that's why I shown an example of specific query that's running slow(for autocomplete). Also, isn't request time of 20,156.21 ms for Controller.startup bigger problem than 2502 ms for SQL.

Comment: You have not shown an sql query, or the time it takes to run _on the database_. When you know what the code is doing for 20,156.21 ms it'll be possible to say if it's a bigger problem :). I would recommend with starting by testing a static page - as that eliminates the db as a factor.

Comment: The database performance is not very good, but it's not the cause of the problem. That long delay smells like apache - rewrite - routing issue.

Comment: Hey @MultiLoad, did you find a solution? was the problem regarding indexes or sql queries performance or something else?

Comment: @fabricio: main problem was that database is running on the cloud, so when i run application and database locally performance is a little faster but far from optimal

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but here's how I fixed it :

1. change the debug level to false (for Production mode) in app.php found in the config folder

   ```
   'debug'=> filter_var(env('DEBUG',false),FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
   ```
2. run this command to generate optimized autoload files. This will prevent time consuming class loading:

   ```
    php composer.phar dumpautoload -o
   ```

If composer.phar is not installed, download it using this command (if your server is running on linux) :

```
     curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Remember to install composer on the application root file where eventually you have composer.json
Hope this helps!